# How to set number of pager links visible?

Tags: drupal-7, pager

How to set number of pager links visible in custom query?

This code returns 9 links, but I want only 5.

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already know:

It's possible set this in theme_pager().